# powerapps and Sharepoint list over 500 items

Tags: powerapps

I'm using this code to try to add more than 500 items to a collection from a SharePoint list with about 1800 rows.  WHy is the collection only showing the first 500 items?  I saw the code on [powerusers.microsoft.com](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/500-item-limit-in-CDM-entity-search-filter-need-to-switch-to-asp/td-p/18134/page/4) and people accepted that it worked.
Perhaps the problem is that I'm using a numeric field on SharePoint instead of a Big integer on CDS.

```
ClearCollect( HundredChart, { Number: 1 }, { Number: 2 }, { Number: 3 }, { Number: 4 }, { Number: 5 
 }, { Number: 6 }, { Number: 7 });
UpdateContext({firstrecord: First(LargeSPList)});
UpdateContext({lastrecord: First(Sort(LargeSPList,ID,Descending))});
UpdateContext({maxiter: RoundUp((lastrecord.ID-firstrecord.ID)/500,0)});

ClearCollect(iter,
AddColumns(AddColumns(Filter(HundredChart,Number<=maxiter),"min",(Number-1)*500),"max",Number*500)
);

Clear(datasource_temp);
ForAll(iter,

  Collect(datasource_temp,
  Filter(LargeSPList,ID >= firstrecord.ID + min && ID < firstrecord.ID + max)) 

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.  The point is we cannot use ID as an integer field and we cannot use calculated field.  Therefore, I set up a new number field ID_Val.

```
   Set(
   firstRecord,
   First(LargeTestList)
   );
Set(
lastRecord,
First(
    Sort(
        LargeTestList,
        ID_Val,
        Descending
    )
)
);
Set(
iterationsNo,
RoundUp(
    (lastRecord.ID_Val - firstRecord.ID_Val) / 500,
    0
  )
 );
ClearCollect(iterations, Sequence(iterationsNo,0));
Clear(datasource_temp);
ForAll(
iterations,
With(
    {
        prevThreshold: Value(Value) * 500,
        nextThreshold: (Value(Value) + 1) * 500
    },
    If(
        lastRecord.ID_Val > Value,
        Collect(
            datasource_temp,
            Filter(
                LargeTestList,
                ID_Val > prevThreshold && ID_Val <= nextThreshold
            )
        )
    )
    )
);
```